# Is there a closed form solution to the expected value of the maximum of iid random variables?

Tags: self-study, expected-value, order-statistics

Let $f_{Xmax}(x)=nf_X(x)F_X(x)^{n-1}$ be the usual pdf of the maximum of iid random variables with density and cumulative distributions f_x and F_X respectively.

Is it possible to obtain a closed expression for the integral

$E(Xmax)=\int_{X}xnf_X(x)F_X(x)^{n-1}dx$

That is, without plugging an actual $f_X$ or $F_X$.

Comment: If n = 1, is there always a "closed" form? Things aren't going to magically get easier when n > 1.

Comment: Is there? I did try but got nowhere. That is precisely what I was asking. I thought I was missing a trick or something.

Comment: Let $G$ be literally *any* distribution function.  Define $F(x)=G(x)^{1/n}$.  This, too, will be a distribution function. Then your question asks whether it is possible to "obtain a closed expression" for the expectation of $G$.  In other words, it is so broad as to be unanswerable--or trivially answerable, depending on your point of view.

Comment: @whuber the question was simply if the integral can be evaluated given only the information that f and F are a pdf and it's corresponding cdf respectively. For example, if I asked the same question of $\int_Xnf(x)dx$, then the answer would be n. Another way of phrasing the question is can that integral be evaluated in a way that the integral sign is gone but I still have say f and F terms.

Comment: My point is that your question is equivalent to asking how to evaluate *any* expectation that could show up in the theory of probability and statistics!

Comment: @whuber Not really. My question is basically "can that integral be simplified any further?" and I think I already got my answer. Like from a basic calculus point of view, I cannot see how I could further evaluate it but I brought it up in case I was missing some distribution/calculus trick. Apparently, I am not and there is no way to simplify that further without setting $f$ to something. Thanks!